# can't add a integer column to an existing table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to add a column to an existing table, of type integer with a constraint of 11 number

I'm running this command:

```
ALTER TABLE pages ADD COLUMN order INTEGER(11);
```

but I'm getting an ERROR 1064 (42000)

Comment: Hint: reserved words. (The error message text should have indicated around the location of error too - at the very least, *include the full error message in questions*!) I recommend choosing a more descriptive name, if possible, such as `pageNumber` or whatnot.

Answer (score 3):

`order` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL.  Use

```
ALTER TABLE pages ADD COLUMN `order` INTEGER(11)
```

> Reserved words are permitted as identifiers if you quote them

or just choose a different name.

Comment: Don't use a reserved word as a column name.  It will cause heartache and sorrow down the road.